# GridView dont use all available space with different items

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have a GridView that I assign to a LinearLayout.
The GridView should use all the space in height (match_parent).
But the GridView just grows in height with its contents and dont use all available space.
Cause of this, the GridView shows a ScrollViewer though dont need it.
The ScrollViewer is shown, when the height of the items in the GridView are different.
What can I do, that the GridView uses the full height, or dont use the ScrollViewer when dont need it?

In this LinearLayout I put the GridView:

```
<LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
              android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
              android:id="@+id/incCon1"
              android:layout_weight="5"
          android:orientation="vertical"
             >
```

This is the GridView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"

               >
    <GridView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/gvContactContent1"
              android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
              android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

I put put the GridView with "addView()" to the LinearLayout code behind.

best regards

Comment: Why you use GridView here? It's function - display long lists in multimple columns and rows, with views reusing logic. And yes, it scrollable. May be using of GridLayout or TableLayout will be better here?

Comment: It makes sense for me to use GridView there. I need the dynamic with columncount for example. Why does the GridView not use the whole space, when its height is set ot "match_parent"